# Hive non-equi Join on OR condition

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have two tables I want to join on 3 keys.  However, one of the keys may contain a value that doesn't exist in the other table, but I still want to retain these records upon query.

Something similar to this where key_3 in the *first_table* may contain a value of 0 which does not exist in the *second_table*.

```sql
SELECT
  f.key_1,
  f.key_2,
  f.key_3,
  s.column_4
FROM 
  first_table f
  LEFT OUTER JOIN second_table s
    ON f.key_1 = s.key_1
    AND f.key_2 = s.key_2
    AND (f.key_3 = s.key_3 OR f.key_3 = 0)
```

When I run this I get an error of **OR not supported in JOIN currently '0'**. I know in newer versions of Hive this is allowed, but is there a workaround for it in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Move condition with OR to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
  f.key_1,
  f.key_2,
  f.key_3,
  s.column_4
FROM 
  first_table f
  LEFT OUTER JOIN second_table s
    ON f.key_1 = s.key_1
    AND f.key_2 = s.key_2
WHERE f.key_3 = s.key_3 
   OR f.key_3 = 0
   OR s.key_1 is NULL --allow not joined records
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand your question, but doesn't a simple `left join` do what you want?

```
SELECT f.key_1, f.key_2, f.key_3, s.column_4
FROM first_table f LEFT OUTER JOIN
     second_table s
      ON f.key_1 = s.key_1 AND
         f.key_2 = s.key_2 AND
         f.key_3 = s.key_3 ;
```

If there is no match in the second table -- regardless of the values in the first table -- the rows from the first table are still returned.